# PHP Combobox from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, combobox, while-loop

I'm doing my homework and we're supposed to do registration, and i'm stuck at combobox, it does show something but it shows a blank , we're prohibited to use mysql_query, and any other object than PDO.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbltypkon";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){                                                 
       echo "<option value='".$row['ID_TYPKON']."'>".$row['TYPKONTAKTU']."</option>";
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if you have right column names in array?

Comment: Also turn on error reporting in php or web server to see where is the problem

Comment: Yes, i did, though it still is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

you should use

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

see [PDOStatement::fetch in the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: Check the HTML source if there is any option or error message?

Comment: so where does it stop? do you see the </select>? Is there anything in the table at all? Are the field names correct? Try a `print_r($row);` in the loop.

Comment: Yes. But if there is no data it cannot display anything.You only showed the table layout

Comment: there is data, 4 Types of contact.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: when you look at the page and use the `View Document Source` function of your browser. You need to look at the output of PHP that you get via HTTP

Comment: view-source:https://student.sps-prosek.cz/~zwievo13it/sqlreg/register.php sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: There you can see the error message `<b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in <b>/var/www/html/zwievo13it/sqlreg/register.php</b> on line <b>111</b>`

Comment: you need to tell it to connect to the database before you can send a query

Comment: that's good. now at the top you need to include that file a la `include "connect.php";`

Comment: it's connected to the file through include, and it is allright i'm sure. it may also be issue on server side, because it crashes a lot of times..

Comment: Yes but the error measage is that $db is not defined, so it does not seem to be included. You could try to copy the code to be sure.

Comment: thank you so much for everything, it was because of $db=null; i forgot to erase it now i can see it

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `$db` variable, i.e. connect to the database